# python regex find/match one or more in a string

Tags: python, regex

I almost can't see anymore for searching google and this site for solutions to my problem.

I want to pick out one or more sequences of two different strings of text from a string:

e.g. `'aSATMPA23.37aSAAWAKE----aSABATT2.05-aSASLEEPING-'`

So I'd like to be able to pick out the 'aSATMPA23.37' and if it's there also the 'aSABATT2.05'.

I've tried the following:

```
import re
serialdata = 'aSATMPA18.5-----aSBBATT2.97-aSBSLEEPING-'
def regex_serialdata(data):                                   
    GrandRegex = re.compile(r'(aS(.)(TMPA)(\d+\.\d+))|(aS(.)(BATT)(\d+\.\d+))')
    match = GrandRegex.match(data)
```

but this stops after only the first match of 'aSATMPA18.5'

Next I tried using 'findall' method:

```
def regex_serialdata(data):                                   
    GrandRegex = re.compile(r'(aS(.)(TMPA)(\d+\.\d+))|(aS(.)(BATT)(\d+\.\d+))')      
    match = GrandRegex.findall(data)
    print(match)
```

Which resulted in: `[('aSATMPA18.5', 'A', 'TMPA', '18.5', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', 'aSBBATT2.97', 'B', 'BATT', '2.97')]`

Is there a better way to do this?

Can I access the values within the list of tuples easily?

Please note, I have spent hours on this and don't ask for help lightly.

Much appreciated,

Paul

Comment: sorry typo, re-edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = 'aSATMPA23.37aSAAWAKE----aSATMPA15.14-aSASLEEPING-'
>>> re.findall(r'aSATMPA\d+.\d+',a)
['aSATMPA23.37', 'aSATMPA15.14']
```

If You place the parenthesis like below, You can get a list of tuples with the values that You want from every match:

```
>>> a
'aSATMPA23.37aSAAWAKE----aSBBATT2.05-aSASLEEPING-'
>>> b = re.findall(r'(aS)(ATMPA|BBATT)(\d+.\d+)',a)
>>> b
[('aS', 'ATMPA', '23.37'), ('aS', 'BBATT', '2.05')]
>>> b[0][0]
'aS'
>>> b[0][1]
'ATMPA'
>>> b[0][2]
'23.37'
>>> b[1][0]
'aS'
>>> b[1][1]
'BBATT'
>>> b[1][2]
'2.05'
```

Comment: thanks for that, I need the partentises so I can extract further parts of the data i.e. from 'aSATMPA23.37' I want the 23.37 as a temperature value and SA as a device address.

Comment: @Tullio_IRL check my edit now.. is that what You want? Because I'm not sure what is the desired result.

Comment: Yes I think that's it, just adjusting the parentheses a little;

b = re.findall(r'aS(.)(TMPA|BATT)(\d+.\d+)',a)

Answer (score 2):

> > Is there a better way to do this?

Yes. Get rid of all of your parentheses:

```
import re
serialdata = 'aSATMPA18.5-----aSBBATT2.97-aSBSLEEPING-'
def regex_serialdata(data):
    GrandRegex = re.compile(r'aS.TMPA\d+\.\d+|aS.BATT\d+\.\d+')
    match = GrandRegex.findall(data)
    print (match)

regex_serialdata(serialdata)
```

> > Can I access the values within the list of tuples easily?

Yes. From your second example, try `print(match[0][0], match[1][4])`.

Comment: thanks for that, as I commented above I need to parse further the returned values hence the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Try following regex:

```
r'(aSA(?:TMPA|BATT))(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'
```

Full Code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(aSA(?:TMPA|BATT))(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', re.DOTALL)

test_str = """
aSATMPA23.37aSAAWAKE----aSABATT2.05-aSASLEEPING-aSATMPA23.37aSAAWAKE--
--aSABATT2.05-aSASLEEPING-aSATMPA23.37aSAAWAKE---
-aSABATT2.05-aSASLEEPING-aSATMPA23.37aSAAWAKE-
"""

for m in re.finditer(p, test_str):
    print('{0:<15}{1}'.format(m.group(1), m.group(2)))
```

It will print:

```
aSATMPA        23.37
aSABATT        2.05
aSATMPA        23.37
aSABATT        2.05
aSATMPA        23.37
aSABATT        2.05
aSATMPA        23.37
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ4kW5/7)

Based on your input, it will capture

- aSATMPA23.37
- aSABATT2.05

Comment: great stuff but there is the possiblity of there being more aSATMPA23.14 or aSABATT2.50 values and your regex pattern doesn't seem to capture further ones.

Comment: it will capture all. I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied and contributed, with your help I've come up with the following:

```
import re

serialdata = 'aSATMPA18.5-----aSBBATT2.97-aSBSLEEPING-'

def regex_serialdata(data):                                  
    GrandRegex = re.compile(r'aS(.)(TMPA|BATT)(\d+.\d+)')

    match = GrandRegex.findall(data)

    print(match)
for x, y, z in match:   
    if y == 'TMPA':
        print('Temp is %s' % z)
    elif y == 'BATT':
        print('Battery is %sv' % z)
```

This produced the following output which is exactly what I want:

```
[('A', 'TMPA', '18.5'), ('B', 'BATT', '2.97'), ('B', 'TMPA', '24.18')]
Temp is 18.5
Battery is 2.97v
```

I'm delighted, it even looks pretty :)

Many thanks,

Paul